# How to import outside Modules or Plugins Dynamically using import() feature of typescript 2.4 in Angular CLI production generated script

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import

The typescript 2.4 `[import()][1]` feature help to load module dynamically. I have tried this feature and it works nicely. I am able to load module and components together dynamically whenever it written in typescript and the imported modules are in same folder.

**The problem start when I have tried to build it in production mode**. I am using `Angular-CLI` and build my project in production mode and it generated `javascript` bundles. Now I am confused to load the modules.

I am developing a plugin based feature where one can add different plugins dynamically. So, these plugins are separated from the Main app and can be added dynamically using `import()` method. At the beginning, I developed the plugins in typescript and those plugins are loaded using `import()` method perfectly. But in production mode, the plugins should be a `javascript` library that can import using `import()` method.

So, I converted the plugins into a library using https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library. and tried to import the index.js file. But it is giving a error message `"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'."`

The following code I have used to import modules and components dynamically.

```
export class DynamicComponent {    
        injector: Injector;
        compiler: Compiler;
        @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) 
        container: ViewContainerRef; 
        componentRef: any; 

        constructor(private compFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, injector: Injector,
            private apiService: apiService) {

            this.injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(COMPILER_PROVIDERS, injector);
            this.compiler = this.injector.get(Compiler);
        }
        addWidget(){

          apiService.getMoudleUrls().subscribe( module_url=>{
            let module_= import(module_url); //e.g './data-widget/data-widget.module'    
            module_.then(module_data =>{

            const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( module_data );
            let moduleFactories = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(module_data[keys[1]]);
            const moduleRef = moduleFactories.ngModuleFactory.create(this.injector);
            const componentFactory = moduleFactories.componentFactories
             .find(e => e.selector === 'data-widget'); // find the entry component using selector       
            this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory, null, moduleRef.injector);

            const newItem: WidgetComponent = this.componentRef.instance; 
       },
      error=>{});
     }
    }
```

Example module and components are

data-widget.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ...,
  declarations: [DataWidget],
  exports: [DataWidget],    
  providers:    [],
   entryComponents: [DataWidget]               
})
export class DataWidgetModule {
    constructor(private widgetService: widgetService) {
      widgetService.register('weather', DataWidget);   
    }        
 }
```

data-widget.component:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'data-widget',
   templateUrl: 'data-widget.component.html'
   })
   export class DataWidget{}
```

So, How can I load external modules in production mode?

Answer (score 0):

The library that you're talking about is for building `npm packages`, with Angular 2/4.

You create an `npm package` and publish it to [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/) . Once it's uploaded you can import it by installing the package in your project via `npm`.

Example:

Make a library called `myLib`

Inside you have a service called `MyService` that's exported in `/exports.ts` file

When you upload the library to `npm registry` you can import it in your project by first installing it with `npm install --save myLib`.

Then import in your module like `import { MyService } from 'myLib/exports';`

Comment: This is a normal process. But I am importing the modules dynamically where the modules are unknown by the app. In my above mentioned code, we don't need to import modules by code  'like import { MyService } from 'myLib/exports';'  We need to provide only the url of the module which pass as a parameter of the 'import()' method and the module load dynamically and after loading module I compile it and get the entrycomponents. So, all these are working. My problem is in production generated script where I would like to only give the url of module and automatically load as it loading now.

Comment: You're trying to implement what's called `lazy loading` ? If that's the case then there's no point in making `npm packages` and you should rather make regular modules just don't register them in your `app.module`. 
How to dynamically load dependencies I do not know as that's not how it should be done. See if this link helps: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: yes, its lazy loading but dynamically and its working nicely with `import()` feature of typescript 2.4. `import()` dynamically load module. you just need to pass a location url of the module and don't need mention the module any where in the app. You can find an example here https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-tips-dynamic-module-imports-with-the-angular-cli. My code working fine in developing mode. I have just need a solution for production generated script.